# How to install jquery Mansory plugin in Drupal?

Tags: jquery, drupal, masonry

I installed modules Masonry API and Masonry Views. From http://masonry.desandro.com/ page I downloaded the masonry.pkgd.min.js file and put it in /sites/all/libraries/masonry then I changed it name to jquery.masonry.min.js

Unfortunatelly, the /admin/reports/status shows:

> jQuery Masonry    not detected 
>   The version of the jQuery Masonry library could not be detected.

Any ideas what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

When I used this version: http://desandro.github.io/masonry/jquery.masonry.min.js
all went just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same issue using http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/masonry-7.x-3.x-dev.tar.gz, June 25, 2015 distro.

I resolved it by downloading http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js and placing it in the sites/all/libraries/masonry folder (sites/all/libraries/masonry/masonry.pkgd.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have renamed it. The Masonry API looks for that script (by specific filename) in that directory.  I had this problem, but then put the files exactly where it says in the instructions (as opposed to my Drupal version's file structure, for instance) and with the same exact name.  I had to create the '/sites/all/libraries/' folders, and placed the files in there to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error as the op, it went away when I put the API in a */dist* subfolder, as per installation instructions. 
So: `[root]/libraries/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, please provide some explantation as to why this is the preferred solution.

Comment: Hi 666, sorry, I don't understand your question. I had a similar error as the op, it went away when I put the API in the correct folder. That's no *preferred* solution, it's just *a* solution. 
May not solve the problem for 99% of the people searching on this issue -- but if it solves the problem for the remaining 1% it's worth the trouble of mentioning it here, I figured.

Comment: What I mean is that your answers here should be usually longer than 1 sentence, where 50% of it is code (or in this case a path). it doesn't help people understand the root of issue. It may help someone of course, but it could help 20% instead of 1% if it was better explained.